# How do I make a message box = a cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, msgbox

I have a long function in which data is moved from "Extract" to "bot", cleaned up and checked against "Queue" for duplicates, and then all unique data is moved to "Queue". Once all of that script has run, I would like a to be brought the the "Queue" sheet, and then have msgbox appear that shows how many rows of data were just moved over.

I have a setformula line in my code that has the number of rows moved over (BW1 in the "bot" sheet), but cannot figure out how to add this number to my msgbox.

What I would like the box to say is "value in cell BW1" + "new claims have been added to the queue"

This is what I've created so far:

```
function message() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Queue").activate(); 
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("bot");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 72);
  var data = range.getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(data + "new claims have been added to the queue");
}
```

Comment: Is the sheet name "bot" or "Bot", sheet names are case sensitive?

Comment: The sheet name is "bot", I mistankingly said "Bot" in the question.

Comment: What do you mean, "make a message box = a cell value"? What's wrong with what you have currently?

Comment: Right now all I can get the message box to say is "new claims have been added to the queue". What I would like the box to say is "value in cell BW1" + "new claims have been added to the queue"

Comment: Your code should work, are you positively sure of the row and column numbers?  Maybe you might try in A1 notation to be sure...?

Comment: A! notation worked! Thank you!